# order a list of stings in r

Tags: r, string, sorting

The data I have include two variables: `id` and `income` (a list of characters)

```
id <- seq(1,6)
income <- c("2322;5125",
           "0110;2012",
           "2212;0912",
           "1012;0145",
           "1545;1102",
           "1010;2028")

df <- data.frame(id, income)
df$income <- as.character(df$income)
```

I need to add a third column `income_order` which includes the ordered values of column income. The final output would look like

NOTE: I would still need to keep the leading zeros

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could split the string on `";"`, `sort` and `paste` the string back.

```
df$income_order <- sapply(strsplit(df$income, ";"), function(x) 
                          paste(sort(x), collapse = ";"))
df

#  id    income income_order
#1  1 2322;5125    2322;5125
#2  2 0110;2012    0110;2012
#3  3 2212;0912    0912;2212
#4  4 1012;0145    0145;1012
#5  5 1545;1102    1102;1545
#6  6 1010;2028    1010;2028
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
df$income_order <- gsubfn("(\\d+);(\\d+)",  ~ paste(sort(c(x, y)), collapse=";"), df$income)
df$income_order
#[1] "2322;5125" "0110;2012" "0912;2212" "0145;1012" "1102;1545" "1010;2028"
```